# Is there a way to buy SO reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, gaming-the-system

Is there a feature by which we can buy reputation on SO (e.g 100 rep for $1)?, or a bot by which we can hack and increase our reputation?

Comment: *"Is there any bot by which we can hack and increase our rep?"* Well, at least you're being honest about not being honest.

Comment: LOL :D This isn't a poker site

Comment: Shouldn't this be a [meta-tag:feature-request]? :)

Comment: @Mysticial No, he's asking if there is a way, not about adding a way to do that.

Comment: Buying or hacking points ain't going to raise your reputation towards me...

Comment: In that case i would like to buy more reputation that Jon Skeet :P ( Ready to pay 1 Rep for 100$ )

Comment: He didnt say it SHOULD be possible.  He asked if it IS possible.  Valid question.

Comment: Well, you could always hire a freelancer to increase your reputation. It ain't done with $1 / 100 rep however.

Comment: I donno what he will get with a 100 rep, atleast a 10 k rep has got some powers.

Comment: @SreeCharan cant you then buy 10k rep for $100 .....:P that was just an example of how much it should cost for 100 rep....:P

Comment: This is such a hilariously bad idea. If you want to donate to the site, email the team, however you're not here to GET TEH REPZ, you're here to answer and ask questions and share the knowledge (or, you should be at least). And "how do i hack teh site?" just...well, words fail me.

Comment: BAD IDEA BUT I offer an answer.   You can in fact do this.  (not that I have, but there is a way).  find someone with a lot of cred and offer to pay them for it.  They offer a bounty on a question, and they mark your answer as accepted.  100 USD to someone in another country might be worth it to them.

Comment: Oh.. addendum.  some employers are using overflow reps as indicators of quality.  (admittedly sloppy ones but it happens)  Proof of this can be found in the adverts to submit your CV to stackoverflow.. I'm sure I've seen a ref to rep's Personally I put zero stock in em, but there is a reason someone would want what they didn't earn.  Twitter followers anyone?

Comment: so basically, should we commercialize a perfectly good site so that it is a question of who is the richest? According to your suggestion, somebody should be able to buy the amount of reputation I have for a mere $12!

Comment: The only way to purchase reputation is by using "Unicoins". But you'd have to have purchased them on April 1st. I tried to pay with bacon as an alternative payment, but due to technical issues with the site SO was not accepting bacon. More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227418/can-i-buy-reputation-with-unicoins

Comment: You could try to ask some guru if he/ she would sell his whole account to you ;-)

Comment: You could keep asking for ways to cheat the system, then pay some to claim ownership of your account. You would be effectively buying reputation, since all the negative reputation points you gain from trying to cheat the system would disappear.

Comment: @Lucifer still want to buy more reputation that Jon Skeet? I take bank transfers and PayPal :D

Comment: Sorry, [xkcd already did it](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Answer (score 122):

As a matter of fact you can. All it costs you is *quality answers* or *quality questions*. Heck, some people even do *quality edits for reputation*. Sign up now and we'll even throw in 100 rep when you associate your account on any other SE site if you hit 200 rep on any site, ABSOLUTELY FREE!

And yes that's the secret. Use the network as it's meant to be used.

Comment: BUT WAIT!  THERE'S MORE!  If you order now, we'll give you your very own unicorn*, just pay separate shipping and handling! (*unicorns may or may not really exist)

Comment: @RocketHazmat http://www.cornify.com/

Comment: But that costs time.

Comment: Time and knowledge are the currency of SE

Comment: The only reason I'd ever want to buy rep is to offer bounty on a question, there should be some way to do that, right?

Answer (score 27):

From: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

> It determines, to an extent, your familiarity with the site, the amount of subject matter expertise you have and the level of respect your peers have for you.

That would not work at all if you could simply buy reputation, or gain it through devious means (like using a bot).

So no, you can't buy rep, and no, you shouldn't try to game the system - that will very likely be caught (and corrected). Moderators and the site owners already have tools to deal with voting fraud and other suspicious activity.

Answer (score 22):

There are drawbacks:

- We need people answering questions. You gain rep for answering questions and we need that motivator to get the answers.
- We don't want everybody being able to buy priviledges. That can lead to abuse and misuse.
- Reputation is also a trust indication. What sense does it make if you can buy it?
- This would also be unfair. We don't want that people with money are able to buy rep and others living in poor (countries) not being able to do it.
- Like @Servy said: If everyone can just buy rep to put up a bounty then a bounty won't be so special anymore. This feature lives from the fact that not everyone uses it.

Answer (score 17):

**A reputation market makes the voting system useless.– *[Tamara Wijsman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148785/is-there-a-way-to-buy-so-reputation/148787#comment427811_148787)***

The meaning of up vote is that the question/answer is useful/constructive and useful in future. So the user up vote the question/ answer and the asker/giver get the reputation, so in that case the selling reputation makes no sense.

Comment: Or in other words: "A reputation market makes the voting system useless."

Answer (score 7):

Bounties are more than an incentive to draw eyes and answers to a question. They are a mark that someone is willing to stake his or her reputation on the quality of the question and the desirability of an answer. It is a way of saying: In my professional opinion, this question has merit (to the extent that SO reputation indicates professional expertise).

Introducing money into the equation will reduce the weight of expertise. Help vampires with a pocketful of cash can place bounties on ridiculous questions that have been purposefully ignored by the community, thus reducing the overall usefulness of the bounty system.

Comment: And that is excatly a problem. This prevent huge number of people who are beginer to the programming from using bounites.

Comment: @SNash: Remember, other people can add a bounty to your question. ^_^

Comment: @SNash Beginning programmers can ask simple questions, and those questions can be (and often are) simply answered. The problem is with the beginning programmers who would misuse the system as a way to get cheap code when their money would be better spent on consultants or additional learning materials.

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat, do you actively add boutines to beginer level questions?

Comment: @SNash My point must have been unclear. Beginner-level questions don't _need_ bounties: they get answered without them because there are many people on the site able to answer them (or they have already been answered). The questions that need bounties are the ones that are complex, obscure or otherwise extraordinarily difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

What if bounties weren't reputation? Or, whatever you purchase is some kind of other reward points? You would then have rep, and whatever this other thing is.

But you shouldn't be able to convert it into rep, or it could be easily abused.

Comment: To take it the other way, I'm not a big user of SO and only have like 400 rep, yet I can still put up a bounty if needed.