# Don't really low negative counts inadvertently attract attention?

Tags: feature-request, voting

Imagine two questions with the following vote counts: -2 and -8.  Is the difference in vote count relevant in any way to the user?  I find myself more likely to read a -8 question through sheer morbid curiosity, while I would most likely totally ignore a boring -2.  I think the attention a really low negative vote count attracts is an unintended consequence of the vote count system.

Some alternative ways to display negative vote counts that would avoid this are below.  In all cases, the system would still store the exact vote count and it could be displayed to those that have that privilege, if they choose.

- Always display -1, no matter how negative.
- Simply show a negative sign.
- Simply show a blank vote count box.

Comment: And what about the high positive counts?

Comment: @Mysticial I see no problem with high positive counts.  High counts attracting attention is the intended effect.

Comment: In any case, questions with -4 or lower (-8 for metas) are suppressed from the front page. So the system already denies them a lot of attention.

Comment: Interesting suggestion - although I expect it would lead to *more* heavily downvoted content. I'm pretty sure the thought of "oh, it's already at -3, that's punishment enough" is a strong pattern in the community, and prevents plenty of complete train-wrecks from happening

Comment: And then, sometimes, you get questions downvoted to -15 or less. (Those, plus the comments, are always good fun to watch).

Comment: Agreed. Going to the least voted questions on meta is **always** really nice entertainment :D Example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148785/is-there-a-way-to-buy-so-reputation

Comment: @nneonneo i've seen -20 in about 10 seconds before

Comment: @Doorknob: Ooh, that is fun. Know of a good way to find such questions (besides my own -9)? :)

Comment: @nneonneo Questions -> Votes -> Last page :)

Answer (score 4):

Very low negative counts might draw a lot of attention, but they draw negative attention, more down votes, close votes, and they often get deleted or they quickly fade away into obscurity.

I might be a sucker, but to me it seems that even among negatively voted questions, the vast majority of them are **not** actually trolls or spammers, but rather lazy people and that they aren't actually seeking negative attention.

I don't think that this phenomenon is really that serious of a problem.