# Suggestion a way to buy reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, experts-exchange

I suggest a way to buy reputation on SO.

And yes I have seen the following link which is irrelavent:

[Is there a way to buy SO reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148785/is-there-a-way-to-buy-so-reputation)

But my purpose is completely different from the above.

My only purpose for buying reputation is not for looking more important/famous but  to be able to pay for bounties for absolutely critical and time sensetive questions.

I personally don't see a drawback here as SO makes some money here and questioner also get his /her question answered with more priority.

I completely disagree with the follwing statement:

"A reputation market makes the voting system useless".

Famous industry leading websites, such as Expert-Exchange have been using similar methods for making money for years and Expert-Exchange is now highly profitable.

Comment: Interesting concept: I would be strongly against buying reputation, but I might support purchasing a bounty directly, such that the reputation _never_ shows on the purchaser's account. Still, there is potential for abuse, and more subtle problems with mis-alignment of incentives here, so such a feature would need to be examined very carefully.