# Clean up the [use] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [use](/questions/tagged/use) tag is hopelessly general and has no wiki entry. Some usages:

- The `<use>` element in SVG
- Some SQL use syntax
- javascript e.g. use strict
- pretty much anything that "uses" anything else, which covers so so much

There are currently 163 questions tagged as [use](/questions/tagged/use).

Comment: There's a somewhat legitimate use for perl though (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). (Maybe [perl-use] would be better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Rather than standing by and watching the tag go down in flames, because it is often used correctly (especially in the tags I frequent), I've gone through and edited some 70+ questions that were using the tag incorrectly.

---

Nope, I disagree. This is a legitimate use (no pun intended) of the [use](/questions/tagged/use) tag:

[SQL USE with variable name for a database with numeric name 2215](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396993/sql-use-with-variable-name-for-a-database-with-numeric-name-2215)

`USE` is a command used in SQL Server to change database context, and it is problematic because there are restrictions on where it can be used (there's that word again) and a lot of questions about supplying a dynamic database name or including database context switching in a module. I don't believe it would make sense to make it [sql-use](/questions/tagged/sql-use) and [database-context-switching](/questions/tagged/database-context-switching) implies even more ambiguity.

Just because it might be over-used (sigh) in some areas does not make it completely useless (oh my gosh). There are a lot of overloaded and generic keywords that make sense as tags, even if they can be misused. Just because they're appropriate in multiple languages or technologies does not mean that the tag has to take its ball and go home. Do we really need [c++-include](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-include), [asp-include](/questions/tagged/asp-include) and [css-include](/questions/tagged/css-include)? Or do you think [include](/questions/tagged/include) is sufficient as long as the question is also tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) or [css](/questions/tagged/css)? Instead of the generic [table](/questions/tagged/table), do we need [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) and [sql-server-table](/questions/tagged/sql-server-table) and [mysql-table](/questions/tagged/mysql-table) and so on? I would argue that an HTML table is vastly different from a database table (which in turn is probably sufficiently different from a "table" in NoSQL), yet here we are with a single tag that is relatively generic and means different things based on the context of the question and the other tags involved. Why aren't we focusing on much more serious offenders of being hopelessly generic, like [database](/questions/tagged/database), [loop](/questions/tagged/loop), [logic](/questions/tagged/logic) and [design](/questions/tagged/design)? Who with half a brain is going to follow the [database](/questions/tagged/database) or [logic](/questions/tagged/logic) tags? Why is whether a tag has followers or not a measure of its usefulness?

Also, since it is a keyword that is also a very generic and overloaded word in the English language, if I am having a problem with `USE` in SQL Server and I want to search for it without the tag, searching for SQL Server-related questions that contain the word "use" is not very helpful at all:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+sql-server

Whereas with the tag I get much more refined results:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use+sql-server

So my vote is to leave it alone. If you find it being used (!) inappropriately, edit the tags.

Comment: Sure you know SQL so you want to claim it for that, someone else wants to claim it for perl and you can't all have it. sql-use, perl-use make some sense but not use on its own.

Comment: @Robert sorry, but I disagree. There are a lot of overloaded and generic keywords that make sense as tags, even if they can be misused. Just because they're appropriate in multiple languages or technologies does not mean that the tag has to take its ball and go home. Do we really need `c++-include`, `asp-include` and `css-include`? Or do you think `include` is sufficient as long as the question is *also* tagged `c++`, `asp` or `css`?

Comment: Include says this...

A provision that many programming languages provide to allow code (functions, classes, objects) in one file to be used in many others.

Comment: @Robert so edit the tag wiki if you think the tag should explicitly state that it is applicable in many places.

Comment: There isn't anything that connects the usages as use means different things in different programming languages or markup. At least include is the same concept in different languages.

Comment: @Robert that was just an example.

Comment: @Robert how about `table`? That definitely means different things in, say, SQL and HTML. Do we really need to call it `sql-table` and `html-table`? `merge` can also mean one thing in SQL and something completely different in source control. Do we need `sql-merge` or even `sql-server-merge` and `oracle-merge` to account for different behaviors and unique vendor-specific deviations from the standard? To me, you haven't made a very strong case of what burning this tag will solve.

Comment: Would anyone ever follow the "use" tag, or check it to see if there are new questions in it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I doubt it, because any given person doesn't encounter problems with it frequently enough to justify that. However, they may very well be having a problem with it today, and want to search for previous questions that are tagged as such. Without the tag, they are searching for the word "use" which - precisely because it is a generic and overloaded term - is, well, pretty useless.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if follower likelihood leads criteria for keeping a useless tag around, who the heck is following absolutely insanely generic tags like [database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database), [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loop), [logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic) and [design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design)? At least `USE` is a keyword.

Comment: I understand your argument about overloaded tags, and I do (somewhat) agree with it.  But there are places in the tag space where we had to force a prefix on people because they were just typing sentences into the tag editor.  The android tag, for example, has [tag:android-intent] and [tag:android-activity], because `[intent]` and `[activity]` were becoming a terrible mess.  I think we even forced a tag synonym on those folks, to coerce them into using something else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you see that happening with [tag:use]? I looked at several questions and I don't see any evidence of sentence stuffing. They all seemed to be tagged with that keyword because the code in the question was actually using that keyword.

Comment: Only that I'm sorta coming around to the community's idea that tags should really only mean one thing.  [activity] is an overloaded term, but it synonymizes to [android-activity] because that is the most common use.  If people want to tag with some other kind of [activity] they'll have to come up with a new tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know that that's wise to apply universally. Like I suggested above, `merge` in SQL Server and Oracle are not the same. So not only would we need `sql-merge` instead of just `merge` (to avoid conflicting with, say, `merge` in source control or that keyword in other languages), we'd also need `sql-server-merge` and `oracle-merge`. Same with cursors, dynamic SQL, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think rather than trying to achieve the insurmountable and force every single tag in the system to mean one and only one very specific thing, you'll quickly realize that you need to fix the surrounding behavior that causes the actual problem. If a question is tagged `[intent]` but not `[android]`, then that's a problem. `[intent]` on its own is not the problem, but the lack of more helpful context. When someone tags `[sql-server]` and `[use]`, I am never confused that they are talking about SVG or JavaScript.

Comment: The problem with [intent] was not that it didn't also have an [android] tag (it almost always did, when it was associated with Android).  The problem is that it was often used to express "intent," a completely useless concept for categorizing questions, as is [use].  You wouldn't need [sql-server-merge] and [oracle-merge], you would just need [sql-merge] and either [oracle] or [sql-server].  So I do agree that you don't have to take it to the nth degree.

Comment: And we did try to get people to use these tags correctly.  But the only sanctioned way to do it in the system is via tag wikis, and people who type sentences into tag editors generally don't read tag wikis.  So, by synonymizing it to something more specific, we forced them to either accept the more specific tag, or choose something else.

Comment: Finally, solving the problem early is better for everyone.  It's much harder to fix when you have a couple thousand questions with a bad tag than it is when you have 50 or 100.

Comment: But @Robert, we've had 163 in FIVE YEARS. And I haven't looked at every single one, but I have yet to find one of those where it is actually a "bad tag." Can we focus our energies on other bad tags, like [tag:database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) (60K+ questions and counting)?

Comment: I'm afraid we've waited too long to fix that one.  [database] doesn't seem to be a generic tag, in the same way that [intent] or [use] is.  For [use], given the tag velocity you suggested, retagging without any synonyms seems a sensible option.

Comment: @Robert but are you suggesting that all questions with [use] should be re-tagged? If so, I disagree. The question I pointed about above should not be tagged with something silly like [sql-use].

Comment: All I'm saying is that we've dealt with this problem before, and the way we solved it was to decide on a specific meaning for the generic tag, and synonymized the generic tag to the specific one.  Problem solved, permanently.  Whether or not that needs to be done here is an open question.  Maybe it's not important enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm still trying to grasp how "this problem" is even a problem in this case. A question tagged with `[sql-server]` and `[use]` does not cause anyone using the site any grief whatsoever unless they were search for `[use]` in the context of `[perl]` or some other use. Which can also happen if someone searches for `[table]` and they get a bunch of database-related questions when they meant to find questions relating to HTML/CSS. Come on, really? [This is a useful tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table)?

Comment: The only thing that may prevent it from being a problem in this case is the low volume.  But the low volume also makes it easier to fix.  Let me explain it this way: The ambiguity of [use] makes it a meta tag (it cannot stand on its own).  This is true *even if you include the [sql-server] tag in the question.*  There's no way to know just by looking at the tag that it refers specifically to the [sql-use-keyword], nor is there a way to enforce this usage.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and there's no way to tell if `[table]` refers to an HTML table or a database table, especially if the question involves returning database results to a web page. Again, who is this actually a problem for?

Comment: I'll grant you that.  But still, [table] actually *means something,* as does [database].  [use], [intent] and [activity] in their generic forms don't mean anything at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd argue that table means something ambiguous at best, on its own. As does use. I'd also argue that use does actually mean something in the right context, and most of the questions with that tag that I've seen do have context to make it unambiguous and to make it mean something. If all tags needed to be 100% unambiguous on their own, we wouldn't have a whole lot of tags at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You have to admit, though, [use] is not a particularly strong or effective tag.  Time and again, I've argued for more general tags, under the theory that you can always search for two tags, and the community always responds in the same way: *specific tags are better;* they have better system support, are more easily understood, and people are more likely to use them correctly.  After the whole [android-activity] debacle, I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not suggesting it's a strong tag at all, which probably also explains why it has been used 163 questions in the history of StackOverflow. Strong <> useful. When it is used incorrectly, that should be corrected, and I think that occurrence will be quite rare. When it is used in the context of `USE databasename` I see no problem with it being used at all. If you do, then please list why it is a problem specifically in this case; as you well know, there is no blanket way to handle all tags or to lump tags into "too general" or "not general enough" buckets.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: And you have a problem calling it [sql-use-keyword] (or something similar), because? ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey because it's overly and unnecessarily wordy. Nobody calls it a "use keyword" never mind a "sql use keyword". They're using the keyword `[use]` in their code, and are going to use that, just like they use `table` and not `html-table-element` or `insert` and not `sql-insert-statement` or `merge` and not `oracle-merge-command`. Again, what would this actually gain, outside of the theoretical and hypothetical "what if 1000s of people started abusing the [use] tag?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not going to keep arguing with you about this. If you want burn `use` and go fix 163 questions, while we ignore real problems like `database`, be my guest. I don't think there's any point to force users to use `sql-use-keyword` but hey, what the hell do I know?

Comment: @AaronBertrand [sql-use] would suffice.  [html-table], not [html-table-element].  [sql-insert], not [sql-insert-statement].  Vendor-specific tags like [oracle-merge-command] are too specific; [sql-merge] and [oracle] would work better there.  Like I said before, maybe the problem with [use] is too small to worry about; I'm just trying to give you a bit of context where we've deliberately made changes to fix this problem.  Didn't think we were having an argument. [database] is already too big to fix, unless we form a posse.  We should have fixed it sooner.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just don't see any logic in [sql-use] and I am trying to grasp who it helps, exactly. Should all questions tagged [java] and [loop] instead be tagged [java] and [java-loop]? Instead we should worry about questions involving, say, SQL Server that have the tag [use] but do *not* include a tag about databases or a specific platform. And I don't see any of those. I don't have any clue whatsoever why [sql-use] needs to stand on its own. Who is using the [use] tag in any capacity other than those posting questions about its use?

Comment: @RobertHarvey next time [I'll just down-vote instead of attempting to engage in conversation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans). I think I made a pretty strong case in my answer why [use] is a valid tag as long as, like any other tag on the entire network, it's used effectively. Nothing has been accomplished here, and if a tag that isn't causing problems gets burned simply because it was brought up here, while we continue to ignore problems that are too big or too late to fix, that's just sad.

Comment: [java] is not generic.  [loop] is pretty much useless, as is [java-loop].

Comment: I agree, loop is useless. [So why are we still talking about `[use]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops)?

Comment: I'm not :)  I am, however, a bit disappointed that you missed my point that we need to catch these things early, and that you think we are ignoring problems.  Do you really expect me (or anyone else) to sift through 4000 questions to fix a tag that's arguably in the same league as [use]?

Comment: @Robert My point was that I don't agree it's in the same league at all. I think you've been missing that point from my answer and all the way through this conversation. Ciao, Robert.

Comment: Can you help us fix the inappropriate [use] uses?  If you can, we can do that and mark this [status-completed].

Comment: @Robert I think I got them all. Much better solution than burning the tag.

Comment: OK, I fixed up the Tag Wiki.  Based on a cursory Google Search it appears that at least *six* different technologies employ a `use` keyword, identifier or statement; I listed all six, and included instructions to add a tag describing the technology that is being used, with a warning not to use the tag for the generic meaning of the word.  Hopefully we won't wind up here again repeating the same conversation.

Comment: @Robert maybe in 5 more years there'll be another couple dozen questions to clean up. And 90,000 more questions tagged `[database]`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

All meta type tags (`use` `image` `arrays` etc) are always hopelessly useless on their own as they are all generic individually. But they serve a purpose, and so that in itself isn't a valid argument to have `use` removed, as some of the most used tags are like this.

Lack of popularity alone cannot determine removal of a meta tag either, as while only used once a month, might be extremely useful and perfectly outline what a question is going to be relating to.

Consider a question asking about mysql command line "use DatabaseName". Here, tags `use` and `mysql` form a very identifiable impression as to what the question will be relating to. Isn't this the desired result from tags?
Arguably, the `mysql` tag alone is enough in this case as people viewing mysql would assist. However as with the `use` tag, `mysql` alone is way too generic. People with knowledge in using mysql might not use mysql command line, and only mysql functions within in PHP (many use PHPMyAdmin (urgh..)).

Compounding these tags is crazy (as I feel often is the case). I then have to click the tag `mysql-use` to help people with these questions? At least without `mysql-use` tag people will still use `mysql` tag and stand a chance of people helping, albeit still not ideal and should have `use` too.

As with many public things, tag choices comes down to user discretion based on the subject of the question, with or without `use` or compound tags, they can and will often be misused by lack of understanding of their usage and bad choices.
So a better system to push people to the right tags would be better, albeit it hard to do, of course.

I think, while maybe not popular, `use` is useful, and your very argument that it's rarely used (163 questions) can also be used to argue it's therefore not likely being misused either, so why lose it?
Ignore it, forget about it, let it be there to be used when the time is right...