# Reply to comments of own trivial answer

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies, trivial

I posted a trivial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461883/check-if-a-video-is-available) (that I knew would be converted to a comment). It was incorrect and someone replied to tell me. I cannot reply to them now as I cannot post comments yet. I tried to post another trivial answer with a link but it did not convert to a comment, so I just improved upon the answer.

Should it be possible for users that do not have the rep to comment to reply to comments regarding their trivial answer? I'm guessing no since there's no way to know whether it is a reply or if it is a new comment (which we shouldn't be able to post).

In my case, if I did not find/have another answer I would not have been able to communicate with the OP and person who replied to my trivial answer comment.

Comment: Meh. Posting an answer that you know will be turned into a comment because you can't otherwise comment is, IMO, borderline abusive. There is absolutely no need to write extra features to better support this case.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I was just a little frustrated in the moment that I could not comment. 50 rep seems like a lot when just starting but I'll patiently wait, it's not that much.

Comment: Can you explain (not to me, but to future new users) how you managed to learn, as a new user, all about comments?  You already understand the limitations AND ways to get around these.  Most new users scrabble around in the mud, crying for mother, when faced with these situations.  How did you manage to stay clean?

Comment: Well for a long time I lurked Stack Overflow since I am a computer science student. I remember reading meta questions about comments and the controversy surrounding them. Just recently I found out trivial answers with little text and a link to another Stack question would be converted to a comment. That was mainly through trial and error, but I've read about it as well.

Answer (score 7):

> Should it be possible for users that do not have the rep to comment to
>   reply to comments regarding their trivial answer?

Should we allow users to comment in a place they are currently not allowed to comment, when that "place" is a converted answer they should not have posted in the first place because it should have been a comment?

**No**.

---

> I posted a **trivial** answer that **I knew** would be converted to a comment
>
> I tried to post another **trivial** answer with a link but it did not
>   convert to a comment

Why are you *intentionally* using things incorrectly?

It can be frustrating not being able to comment at first, but there are very [good reasons it's like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198667/230506).

And consider that **millions** of users of Stack Overflow had to earn 50 rep to be able to comment.
Surely you are no different to those other users, or deserve something which those other users did not?
We all had to go through the same scenario of not being able to comment, do what *everyone* else did - earn 50 rep :)

> so I just improved upon the answer

This is simply what you should have done in the first place, instead of trying to work around the system.

Answer if you can. 
If you need to comment first, but do not have 50 rep, then wait until someone else has commented and obtained any necessary info, and then you can answer.

Or, answer questions which you do not need to comment on and earn 50 rep.

50 rep is simply not hard to earn. 
You only need an upvote or two on a question or two, and some edit suggestions (which are not hard to find), and a few answer upvotes.
In fact, before this answer/comment scenario you had "yesterday" you already had 14 rep, so only needed to earn another 36 rep.

---

> In my case, if I did not find/have another answer I would not have
>   been able to communicate with the OP and person who replied to my
>   trivial answer comment.

You posted an answer knowing it should be a comment and knowing it would be converted, so there is nothing that requires additional options, and there is no legitimate scenario to accommodate.

You are essentially asking if we can have a new function to assist us when we bend the rules and bypass systems. Which really wouldn't be a good thing. 
Rules and procedures (etc.) are there to keep order, not for us to find ways around them and then request new functionality to cater for it.

---

Related reading regarding the need for 50 rep to comment:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217481/5-rep-to-upvote-and-50-to-comment-really-what-kind-of-community-is-this

Other useful information regarding rep required as a new user, etc.:

- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: [How does lurker gain reputation to receive privilege for commenting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773)