# Can I buy reputation with Unicoins?

Tags: support, reputation, unicoins

It's been said

> With our custom currency, Unicoins, you can now purchase exclusive power-ups that enhance your stay on this site and customize it to your own taste.

I want to buy some reputation with Unicoins. Is that possible?

This is not a question of joking; I am sincere!

Comment: They are coins filled with unicorn magic. Everything is possible with them!

Comment: You should not vote down on a newbie with only 100 reputation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following power-up is available for the low, low price of 90 coins:

[image]

Comment: where Can I found this?

Comment: @zdd It's on page 2 of the "buy powerups" dialog.

Comment: thank you! I see that, you are a good man!

Comment: But I can't buy it now.

Comment: @zdd I hate to be the person to tell you this but Anna is not a man and she is the keeper of the reputation continuum.  There must be a perfect balance between good vs. evil when it comes to the reputation points.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas thanks for point this out, she is a good lady! you are a good man!

Comment: @zdd I hate to be the person to tell you this but GeoffDalgas, although he has an almost perfect name, is not a good man.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait for Unicoins v2.0.