# Can I get my reputation back after April Fool's Day?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, april-fools

This time I am sincere; please don't joke!

I asked [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227418/can-i-buy-reputation-with-unicoins) hours ago, and I got lots of down votes. My reputation has decreased. So can I get it back after April Fool's Day? I really care about my reputation on SE!

Comment: Why? What happens tomorrow?

Comment: @random Ok, why SE put Unicoins on the page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm sorry to hear about your downvotes. Downvotes are non-refundable after 5 minutes. However, we will provide you unicoins to compensate. Please wait 6-8 weeks for processing and shipping.

Answer (score 4):

Downvotes are not an April Fools day joke.

They are there for a reason. You will not get your reputation back unless the downvotes are reversed by their owners or the post is deleted by the community. Or you can post things people value and get upvotes on them, this increasing your reputation.

Comment: wait for delete...